# Issue with POST method in JIRA REST API

Tags: json, post, jira-rest-api

I need to add a user to a group in JIRA using the java REST API. I need to do a POST using the groupname as a query parameter and username as a payload. I am using the Spring RestOperations for the same. This is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("username", abc@cs.com);

Group group = restOperations.exchange(
                "https://cs.jira.com/jira/rest/api/2/group/user?groupname=jira-users",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject, getAuthorizedHttpHeaders(user, pass)),
                Group.class).getBody();
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes here...
The payload is invalid. You need to put a JSON object with **name** as the key:

```
{"name":"abc@cs.com"}
```

It should be:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("name", abc@cs.com);
```

as documented here: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/group-addUserToGroup.

However the current exception you got is caused by the fact that you pass a *JSONObject* to your *HttpEntity*. No mapping message converter exists for a *JSONObject*.

It should be:

```
new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), getAuthorizedHttpHeaders(user, pass))
```